# CFWheels: Using SQL Functions in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfwheels

I faced an issue while trying to use SQL function in where clause of CfWheels's findAll() method.

```
<cfset currencyInfo= model('pricelist').findAll(select="currencyid,name",where="YEAR(startDate)=#params.year#")>
```

The confusing thing here is that while using the sql function in the select clause of the same statement, it works like a charm.

```
<cfset currencyInfoTest= model('pricelist').findAll(select="currencyid,name,YEAR(startDate) AS Year",where="id=5")>
```

I guess CFWheels might be processing the column mappings in the select clause only and not any calculated or operated syntax in the where clause.

I need to use some sql functions in the where clause as above. Any ideas?

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't know.  In this particular case, don't.  Create start and end date variables from params.year and go with startDate >= Jan 1 of params.year and startDate < Jan 1 of params.year + 1.  Your query will run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that CFWheels does not allow SQL functions in the `where` argument. It parses the string for property names so it can map them to columns in the database, and it also applies `<cfqueryparam>` bindings to the values passed in. But it is unable to parse out calls to SQL functions.

However, you can create a [calculated property](http://cfwheels.org/docs/chapter/calculated-properties) based on the SQL function that you need and query against that.

In `models/PriceList.cfc`:

```
function init() {
  property(name="startDateYear", sql="YEAR(pricelists.startdate)";
}
```

In your `findAll` call:

```
currencyInfo = model('pricelist').findAll(select="currencyid,name", where="startDateYear=#params.year#");
```